# I want to use for loop on XPath in Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, xpath

```
xpath = '//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[1]'
```

This xpath is for the first item of a search result on amazon.

I want to use for loop using XPath to open every item in list one by one.
**How to use for loop for this result?**

xpath = '//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[{}]'

list  = ['//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]']

```
for number in range(len(list)): 
  print(number) 
  xpath = xpath.format(number)
```

Comment: Please provide at least some code.

Comment: please edit your question and provide the code properly formatted. Don't put relevant code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
results = []
xpath = "//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]"

for element in driver.find_alements(xpath):
    # do someting with each element here
    results.append(element)
```

Comment: Undefined variable 'driver'

Comment: can i share my full code with you?

Comment: Oh you'll need to initialize the driver first of course:)